# Error occured while moving data from SQL Server to MySQL using SSIS ODBC Destination Batch method

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, odbc, oledbconnection

I am trying to move data from SQL Server to MySQL using SSIS. I have used **OLE DB Source** for fetching data from SQL Server and **ODBC Destination** to push data into MySQL tables.

I have kept row by row insert method which is working fine without any error but it is very very slow.

When I tried `Batch Insert` method, the SSIS Package is failing with following error.

> [ODBC Destination[191] Error: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occured. State: 'HYC00' - Native Error Code:0 [MySQL] [ODBC 8.0(w) Driver] [mysqld-5.7.12] Parameter arrays with data at execution are not supported

There are 7 tables having 500 000 records each. It took around 9 hrs to complete using row by row method (no errors but very slow).

But when I choose batch, it is throwing the above error.

How to achieve batch insert for improving the data movement speed? I have installed ODBC 8.0 Driver.

Should I modify the connection string `OR` should I enable any pre-defined variable in MySQL `OR` what method can I try to achieve this.

Comment: Use mysql Workbench and his migration wizard. It supports SQl Server and and odbc as Source

Comment: Actually we want to run this SSIS package every 2 hour once to do the sync between source and destination. Can we do scheduling using Migration Wizard?

Comment: 9.8.10 Data Migration Setup

Provides additional options for data transfer, including the ability to set up a script to automate this transfer in the future.